# How to add divider bars between specific fields in a matrix or table?

Tags: powerbi

As per below.  I have some pretty big (across) tables and they are rather hard to read right now.  In Excel, it is easily possible to insert borders between specific columns or rows that will contextually update as the data changes.  Is there a way to achieve the same result in PowerBI?

[image: example - green bars]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerBi there is limited table formatting options.
There is no way to do what you are asking without workarounds.

The easiest way would be to format the columns with different colors so 3 columns have the same color and then you alternate.

Another solution is that you create dummy measures that you insert between the columns you want to divide, colour the text and background with your boarder color, then you make these columns minimum width.

Another way would be to insert 4 different tables overlapping and sorted the same way. Then you can format the frame for each table to get the result you want.